# three.js get right hand vector

Tags: javascript, three.js

This gives me the forward vector of a Object3d

```
var forward = new THREE.Vector3();
object.getWorldDirection(forward);
```

How do I get the right-hand side vector of the object (using Three.JS)?

Answer (score 3):

My best advice is to NOT include 'three.js' in your Google search when looking help regarding three.js.

I excluded 'three.js' from my searches and found similar questions by people in a Unity community...

Knowing this I found a very simple (admittedly very hacky) solution which works in three.js.

Take a plain-old right-hand vector

```
var right = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0,  0 );
```

And just "turn it" by the object's `.quaternion` value...

```
right.applyQuaternion( object.quaternion );
```

Any (normalized) direction relative to the object's rotation can be gleamed in this fashion

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Lzx683v/

[image: Picture of a Cube, with six smaller cubes orbiting around it's XYZ axis directions]

Comment: I love three.js - and I realise its free. I am owed nothing. I am here to HELP your community; it's why I self-answered my question. But I've also spent countless hours using the three.js docs/support that is out there, and it is ALWAYS unfinished, or doesn't work/fit. Transposing the docs of a more popular framework is geninuely the best advice I could offer to anyone who finds themselves in my situation. I'm frankly not sure how I would phrase the advice in my question differently

Comment: Fixed it for ya. I don't think your answer is "cheating", since applying rotations to a vector is a perfectly acceptable approach. However in WebGL world, right is `(1, 0, 0)`, I'm not sure where you got `(-1, 0, 0)` from, but that information is objectively incorrect. I think you haven't noticed it because your demo has both left and right boxes, but they're swapped. You can see this in action [in the Three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) moving an object to `x = 1` moves it to the right.

Comment: Appriciate the edit! and also very astute of you to notice the incorrect left/right polarity. Thanks!